# Is there a way to deploy newly compiled ASP.NET web application code on IIS 7 without kicking users off?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-deployment, smoothing

Our company releases updates of our rich client application (written mainly with ASP.NET, WCF services, and ASP.NET AJAX) on our client's Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 web server.  Once in awhile, we have large releases of updates.  And sometimes there are bugs that users catch right after the release that are not caught during automation testing nor stage testing.  Is there a way to smoothly deploy ASP.NET code on IIS 7 while users are still on without disrupting their workflows containing code that was not affected?  I've found that if I just copy the code from stage (without the web.config) manually, and paste it into the production web root folder, nobody is really kicked off.  But I'm wondering if there are any side-effects to this strategy for users diligently working in the application.  I'm just wondering if any other connections may get interrupted or how they're even handled in this situation (ie: SQL connection, WCF Service calls, whether they keep the same session and if that will have any impact, etc..)?  If I chose this method, I'd have something in the web.config that would display a message to every user (in the master page)--like a banner, that says "Please log off, and clear your cache", so they would see updates to issues addressed.  But this would only be relevant to the impacted users.

If someone doesn't think this is a good strategy for minor updates, and has a better strategy, like changing a web.config setting that forces the user to a different server or something while the deployment is taking place.  Or some other methodology, my ears are listening.  Obviously the latter sounds safer, but I just don't know how this could be done.  I've read about load balanced servers, but I think this type of server setup is done for different purposes, like if a server goes down, doesn't it?  Or would this be the best solution as you take one site down?  I'm welcome to any idears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to stress about minimal-impact for releases too, but now we take it down. The reality is twofold:

1. You cannot guarantee that everything someone is working on right now is NOT something you're about to update. Consider this: A user is working on x.aspx and is in the middle of a postback. You drop a new x.aspx.
2. With enough notice, maintenance windows are a way of life. Users should expect that, from time to time, you need exclusive access to the application to make updates, etc.

It's just too hard to keep all the plates in the air when you really don't know what someone might be working on while you deploy. Especially if database updates are in the mix!

Comment: I will accept this as the actual answer though... I see your point about SQL updates.. if the client code doesn't match what the SQL database expects, hell can break loose!

Answer (score 3):

If there is a load balancer in the mix: you would remove the server(s) with the old code and add add the server(s) with the new code. This lets the traffic die out on the old code servers without kicking people out. The new server(s) picks up the traffic.

We do this with a new release to one server at a time until we replace all of the code in our server farm. It gives the application time to bake in the real world. If issues comes up, and they have, you only have to revert a single server. using the load balances makes it easier.

It is (usually) a seamless transition. Of course you need to make sure you app can handle any database changes etc.

Comment: I like this answer when the deployment contains simple fixes (ie: no SQL updates, no web service parameter changes, etc..)